# internet problem

Tags: iphone

how to check internet connection through iphone  or  objective-c.???

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802592/internet-problem/1802657

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet you can use:

```
[[Reachability sharedReachability] setHostName:@"example.com"];
if ([[Reachability sharedReachability] remoteHostStatus] == NotReachable) {
    UIAlertView *dialog = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] retain];
    [dialog setTitle:@"Server unreachable"];
    [dialog setMessage:@"The server is temporarily unavailable."];
    [dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
    [dialog show];
    [dialog release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and Drity: Ping Google?

Answer (score 0):

Apple's recommendation is to do something like (or use) [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the apple sample code Reachability. It should provide you with everything you need.